# Python: Assistance on finding shortest route with Dijkstra

Tags: python, graph

I am getting the error message mentioned in the title and I don't understand how to fix it.

What I'm trying to achieve is a graph with an algorithm to calculate the shortest route from City A to City E. I tried using an example code I found from my school materials, but it with number values and not strings. I tried changing it to work with strings but I don't understand the error message.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

```py
import sys

class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, weight):
        self.value = value
        self.weight = weight
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def addNode(self, v, w):
        newNode = Node(v, w)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = newNode

class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.adjList = [None] * 10

    def addEdge(self, u, v, w):
        if self.adjList[u] is None:
            newLL = LinkedList()
            self.adjList[u] = newLL
        if self.adjList[v] is None:
            newLL = LinkedList()
            self.adjList[v] = newLL
        self.adjList[u].addNode(v, w)
        self.adjList[v].addNode(u, w)

    def shortestPath(self, src):
        nodeList = []
        dist = []

        for i in range(len(self.adjList)):
            dist.append(sys.maxsize)

        # Insert first node with destination of 0
        nodeList.append([0, src])
        dist[src] = 0

        while len(nodeList) > 0:
            # Delete first node of nodelist since it has shortest distance
            tmp = nodeList[0]
            del nodeList[0]

            u = tmp[1]

            # Collect all adjacent nodes
            cur = self.adjList[u].head
            while cur:
                v = cur.value
                weight = cur.weight
                # Check if there is shorter path from node v to node u
                if dist[v] > (dist[u] + weight):
                    """If distance to node v is not infinite, node belongs to the list
                    of stored nodes. Remove node from the list and add it again with
                    updated distance value."""
                    if dist[v] != sys.maxsize:
                        for i in range(len(nodeList)):
                            if nodeList[i][0] == dist[v] and nodeList[i][1] == v:
                                del nodeList[i:i + 1]
                    # Update distance
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + weight
                    nodeList.append([dist[v], v])
                cur = cur.next

        # Print distances
        print('Node \t\tDistance from node ' + str(src))
        for i in range(len(self.adjList)):
            print(str(i) + '\t\t' + str(dist[i]))

g.addEdge("City A", "City B", 90)

g.shortestPath("City A")
```

Comment: You need to instanciate your Graph object, before calling any methods, like g=Graph(). Then use g.addEdge()

Comment: @Stefan I had added g = Graph(). I just accidentally missed it from the presentation code.

Comment: you still shouldn't call Graph.addEdge()

Comment: Your next error is that you use strings for nodes, they should be integers in this context.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you I added g = Graph.
Yes I would like to change the code so I could use strings for the nodes. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You could use a dictionary for your linked list, instead of an array. I think, however, that you first should make this code work, them modify it. Note that your nodes here should be 0,1,2...

Comment: There's almost certainly no reason to define your own linked-list class just to implement an adjacency-list representation of a graph. Just use a regular Python `list`, which is already dynamically resizable.

Answer (score 0):

(After correcting the code) you are trying to access the list `self.adjList` using strings (CityA, CityB).
It would be easier to store the cities in a new string list and translate between the strings and positions using the `index` function to keep the algo as is.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and first error message I've got is

> addEdge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'w'

This is because addEdge is not static method. It needs Graph object. So change

```
Graph.addEdge("City A", "City B", 90)
```

to:

```
g = Graph()
g.addEdge("City A", "City B", 90)
```

Then we're coming to next error:

```
     if self.adjList[u] is None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

And this is because adjList is a list, so if you want to pick up an element, you need to provide its position within the list. If you want to use strings instead of position, dictionary might be better option than list, but I'll leave it for you to try.